# What does "lean into" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, definition

I am reading a story and there's a conversation between two young men and I was wondering what "lean into" means in this context. I supposed it meant something like "snuggling" in this context but when I try to search it in google all it says is that its a term used in professional boxing. I will quote the following paragraph:

> "Wait!" cried Antonio, rather surprised at Lovino's speed, and rather elated by his smile. "Wait, Lovino, your ankle!" Lovino drew a breath like a warning and batted Antonio's hand away, but a gasp of laughter finally burst from his lips. "I'm fine!" Antonio's chest flipped. Lovino's laughter was still the most wonderful sound he had ever heard. He had to hear more of it… "Don't be silly, you are injured, **lean into me…**" Lovino's eyes flashed wildly. "You perverted…" Antonio placed a hand on his back… "Hush, that's the pain speaking…"

Comment: I think it means the same as "lean on me," as if to help an injured person limp along, much like one might lean on a crutch.

Comment: "lean into me" implies a more intimate contact than "lean on me". I imagine this was the reason for the comment "You perverted…".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JR – it means about the same as 'lean on me'. Also, there is a subtle second meaning that is, 'don't resist me'.

For other ways this versatile phrase can be used, check out [Sheryl Sandberg's TED talks](https://www.ted.com/talks/sheryl_sandberg_so_we_leaned_in_now_what?language=en) where she uses 'lean in' in a business context.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Urban Dictionary, "lean into" can also mean to ejaculste inside someone.  This makes sense in thecontext.